# WordPress order by date ACF field not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two WordPress argument arrays that I am submitting to `get_posts` for events.

The front-end of the site is tabbed into `Events | Previous Events`

`$today = date('Y-m-d'); // e.g. 2018-01-21`

Here are my arguements:

```
$args = [
"post_type" => "events",
"post_status" => "publish",
"posts_per_page" => -1,
"meta_query" => [
    "key" => "date",
    "value" => $today,
    "compare" => ">=", // Greater than or equal to today's date (Y-M-D)
    "type" => "DATE 
],
"orderby" => "meta_value",
"order" => "ASC"
];
```

And in my query for previous events is for `"meta_query" => "compare" => "<"`

However, I am getting all the events on each tab. None of the events have happened yet so I am expecting to have `previous events` as an empty tab currently.

Looping through them as follows

```
$events = get_posts($args);
foreach($events as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
// Mark up
endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: try adding meta_key="date" ?

Comment: Having added this @TomMillard - I now get nothing back at all for either query.

Comment: I take it `date` is the name of the key in ACF

Comment: Yes, it is @TomMillard

Comment: ACF docs show a basic usage https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/ and the meta_query just append more sql. WP docs show that you do need meta_key. Sorry not sure I can be any more help.

Comment: are you sure, that ACF is not saving the date as a timestamp?

Comment: if you work with timestamps, it should be easy to query through it

Comment: @Stender I have configured ACF to return `U` and have modified `$today = date('U');` - still no luck :/

Comment: if you use timestamps - I think you should use "type" => "number", and "orderby" => "meta_value_num" - PHP is elastic, so it shouldn't care if it is strings VS ints.

Comment: If that doesn't work, i am out of ideas.

Comment: or NUMERIC - not sure

Comment: Tried everything to no avail :(